# Rent a Car - Fort Lauderdale to Maryland

Tags: car-rentals

A few years ago we rented a car to go from Maryland to Florida many times and it was very cost effective.

Today, I'm unable to find a rent a car to go from Florida to Maryland (drop off in Maryland), all of the major rent a car companies say it's not possible to drop off out of state. I found one location but they wanted $800 drop off fee.

Can someone find me a rent a car from Fort Lauderdale, Florida to Maryland (any City) that can be picked up at 10:30PM?

Comment: Pick up at 10:30 p.m. on what date? What date do you want to drop it off?

Comment: You may have problems with "not normal" rental car itineraries.  During 2020 rental car companies sold off a large amount of inventory which has caused rental car prices in popular locations to skyrocket at the moment.  I wouldn't be surprised if they were limiting one way rentals in order to keep what inventory they have in the places where it makes the most money for them

Comment: This is off-topic here. See [The WANTA™ debate](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1445/115023)

Answer (score 3):

No, they can't.

As has been widely publicized, there is a nationwide shortage of rental cars. Warnings about it began [months ago](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurabegleybloom/2021/03/11/a-car-rental-apocalypse-is-coming-heres-what-you-need-to-know/?sh=7ac902b5223e), owing to a confluence of factors: the rental companies' massive fleet-selloffs during the pandemic, the microchip shortage affecting new car deliveries, the surge in rental car demand that exceeded all projections.

In high-demand areas, especially Florida, Arizona, and Hawaii, people have found it cheaper to [rent U-Haul](https://www.caranddriver.com/news/a36217613/hawaii-u-haul-renters-high-prices/) moving trucks than a regular rental car. You might try to find one of those. But if a rental car company can charge $200 a day for a mid-sized car in Ft. Lauderdale, they would be crazy to let anyone take it out of state without charging a hefty penalty fee.